# Бот кликер на Selenium WebDriver PhantomJS. Есть ли другие варианты?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Всем привет. Есть работающий проект бота кликера на C#. Время от времени встречаемся с такой проблемой, что phantomJS не полностью прогружает страницы. Т.е. прогружает некую часть страницы, а основной контент не грузится. Неважно этот контент в другом фрейме или нет, переключение между фреймами используем, джаваскрипт включен, задержки пробовал разные по этой статье [Ожидания](https://kreisfahrer.gitbooks.io/selenium-webdriver/content/webdriver_intro/ozhidaniya.html). Делал скрин, на скрине эти данные также отсутствуют.
Хотелось бы устранить эти моменты.
Смотрел в интернете и ничего нормального на замен PhantomJS не нашел.
Был HtmlUnitDriver под селениум, но, настолько я понял, он только для java.
Можете посоветовать варианты phantomJS, и варианты Seleniumа впринципе, может есть какой-то движок, платные варианты тоже рассматриваю.
Варианты Selenium WebDriver под обычные браузеры, типа FirefoxDriver, не подходят.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй скролить страницу вниз с помощью js.

Иногда проблема именно в этом.

Comment: @Alex Я дал вполне конкретное решение, которое помогало лично мне далеко не 1 раз в подобных ситуациях. Какого это не является ответом?

Comment: Смутило слово "иногда ...", в большинстве случаев это означает, что автор ответа не уверен в своем решении для конкретного вопроса.

Comment: Конечно не уверен. Ведь одна и та же проблема может быть по разных причинах. Особенно в даном случае, ведь одна и та же проблема в рамках разных браузеров может иметь кардинально разные корни. И, даже, в рамках одного браузера может отличатся в зависимости от конкретного сайта. Конкретного решения на все случаи жизни в даной проблеме не существует. Но я указал самое частое решение.